# Can't scan after connect dispose/clear

Tags: java, dispose, rxandroidble

I am connecting to Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device using the library rxandroidble2.

After successful connection to the device,
I'm testing reconnection after forcibly terminating the connection.

Although the disposible for the connection has been disposed, the device does not switch to the advertise state.

Only when turn off the screen of cell phone will the BLE device switch to advertised state and scanning will be possible.

Is there a way to make sure the code disconnects from the BLE device?

Below is my viewmodel code.

```
public void doOnDeviceSelectPage() throws Exception {
        if (rxBleClient == null) {
            initRxBleClient();
            return;
        }

        if (disposable.isDisposed()) {
            disposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        }


        disposable.add(
                onDeviceSelectPageBleUseCase.execute(rxBleClient)
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(
                                rxBleConnectionPair -> {
                                    ScanResult scanResult = rxBleConnectionPair.first;
                                    RxBleConnection rxBleConnection = rxBleConnectionPair.second;
                                    String scannedDevice = new String(scanResult.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData(0xffff));

                                    // Handle each scan result
                                    Log.d("BleConnect", "Device connect: " + scannedDevice);

                                   
                                    onDeviceConnected();
                                    if (scannedDevice.equals("A")) {
                                        deviceController.setRxBleConnection(rxBleConnection);
                                        deviceController.onDeviceConnected();
                                    } 
                                },
                                throwable -> {
//                                    onDeviceDisconnected();
                                    // Handle errors
                                    Log.e("BleScan", "Error: " + throwable.getMessage());
                                    onDeviceDisconnected();
                                }
                        )
        );
    }


    public void onDeviceDisconnected() throws Exception {
        setConnectedDevice(null);

        disposable.dispose();
    }

}
```

I tried removing rxbleconnection and rxbleclient in the viewmodel, but it had no effect.
Even after closing the app, the device did not return to the advertise state, and could only return to the advertise state after closing the screen.

Comment: Could you answer two additional questions:
1. how are you forcibly terminating the connection?
2. what is inside the `onDeviceSelectPageBleUseCase`?

Comment: 2. The 'onDeviceSelectPageBleUseCase' contains logic for scanning and connecting to devices. After scanning for devices, it connects to a device using the 'scanResult', and receives back the 'rxbleConnection' and 'scanResult' as a result.

Comment: 1. In the 'onDeviceDisconnected()' method, I performed 'disposable.dispose()' and null-handled the 'rxbleconnection'.

Comment: I've created a test sample to diagnose the issue.

https://github.com/Kang-BongGuk/rxbleTestSample.git

Comment: I expected the following scenario:

1.Scan and connect to the BLE device.

2.Disconnect from the BLE device -> The BLE device returns to advertising state (visible to other BLE scanners).

3.Conduct another scan to find and reconnect to the BLE device.

Comment: However, the actual scenario unfolded as follows:

1.Scan and connect to the BLE device.

2.Disconnect from the BLE device -> The BLE device does not return to advertising state (not discoverable by other BLE scanners).

3.When turning off the screen of the connected phone(android) the BLE device returns to advertising state (discoverable by other BLE scanners).

4.Conduct another scan to find and reconnect to the BLE device.
         
I'm curious about how to definitively disconnect from the BLE device and make it return to advertising state."

Comment: Please add relevant information to the question post, it will help me and others who later will come here searching for answers. The sample app you provided seems to be different from the code you have posted in the original question. I will stick to the original one. Do you perhaps have the `nRF Connect` app installed on your device?

Comment: I've created a test sample code by stripping away unnecessary parts and focusing only on the essential elements needed for the connection operation from the original code, as the original question's code had too many additional operations and files. The connection method in both the original code and the test sample code remains the same, and the same issue occurs. If the difference between the code in the question and the test sample code is causing the problem, I'll modify the code in the question to match the sample code.

Comment: How do you verify that the peripheral is not advertising?

Comment: 1.Preparation: Prepared an Android device for connecting to the 'BLE device' (referred to as 'connect android') and another Android device for BLE scanning purposes (referred to as 'scan android').

Comment: 2.Simultaneous Scanning: Initiated scanning on both devices while operating the 'BLE device'.

Comment: 3.Connection Establishment: Observed the 'BLE device' being scanned by both Android devices and proceeded with establishing a connection between the 'BLE device' and the 'connect android'.

Comment: 4.Connection Confirmation: Confirmed successful connection between the 'BLE device' and the 'connect android', and observed disappearance of the 'BLE device' from the scanning list on the 'scan android'.

Comment: 5.Disconnection: Disconnected the 'BLE device' from the 'connect android' (the 'BLE device' remains operational).

Comment: 6.Post-Disconnection Scanning: Attempted scanning on both Android devices again. -> The 'BLE device' was not scanned.

Comment: 7. Closing 'connect android': Turn off the screen of the 'connect android'.

Comment: 8.Re-Scanning on 'scan android': Observed that the 'BLE device' is discovered during scanning on the 'scan android'.

Comment: I checked the advertising status of the 'BLE device' using the above method.

Comment: Does your 'connect android' contain `nRF Connect` app?

Comment: I tested with the 'nRF Connect' app as follows:
Scanning for the 'BLE device' and connecting to it -> Back to the 'SCANNER' tab and re-scan for devices (confirmed that it wasn't scanned because it was already connected). -> Returned to the connected tab and disconnected from the 'BLE device' (by pressing the 'x' button on the tab) -> Back to the 'SCANNER' tab and tried to re-scan ( 'BLE device' not scanned ) -> Restarted the 'nRF Connect' app and tried searching again ( 'BLE device' not scanned ) -> Turn off the screen and turn it back on, then tried to re-scan ( 'BLE device' scanned ).